# Regarding Bhadra Kali

Tags: time, durga, kali

This wikipedia article describes kali as being the God of Time and Death - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali

What do they mean by describing her to be the God of time?

Any scriptures/mantras related to Kali are welcomed

Comment: I think, There's a technical difference between Bhadra-Kali & Maha-Kali. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: Oh what's the difference?

Comment: Both are ughra forms of the Mother